# Combobox not showing items, drop down list is blank

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the items from the combobox drop downlist to be shown to the user to be selected. The combobox is being populated by only items that were checked in the checkedlistbox. This is what I have so far and the drop down list is just blank:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To checkListBox.Items.Count - 1
      If checkListBox.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
            comboBox1.Items.Add(checkListBox.Items(i))
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = checkListBox.Items(i)
      End If
Next
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I understanding you correctly that you have a checkListBox and a comboBox, and you want to comboBox to show all the items selected by the user in the checkListBox? That's what I just did, using your code, and it worked perfectly. Or are you trying to do something else? Have you tried putting a break point in and seeing if this *For* loop is ever hit?

Comment: You were understanding me correctly. Maybe my for loop doesn't get hit, I'll go through my code and figure out what's going on. It helps to know that the code itself should work.

Comment: that was my issue, my for loop wasn't getting hit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the ItemCheck event:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Item 1")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Item 2")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Item 3")

End Sub


Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck

    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked AndAlso Not ComboBox1.Items.Contains(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index)) Then
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index))
    ElseIf e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked AndAlso ComboBox1.Items.Contains(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index)) Then
        ComboBox1.Items.Remove(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index))
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```